# In shell, how to remove file if bigger than 100MB, move otherwise

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

What would be the easiest way to do the following with shell commands?

Pseudo code: `rm abc if >100MB else mv abc /tmp`

abc could either be a name of ONE file or ONE directory.

I want to have an alias that if run on a file or directory, it removes it if it's size is greater than 100MB and if not, it moves it to another directory.
I know I could accomplish something similar with a whole fuction, but there must be a slick one-liner that could do the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To move a single regular file if its size is lower than 100MB and delete it otherwise, you can use the following commands :

```
# 104857600 = 1024 * 1024 * 100 = 100M
[ $(stat --printf '%s' "$file") -gt 104857600 ] && rm "$file" || mv "$file" /tmp/
```

To move a single directory and its content if its combined size is lower than 100MB and delete it otherwise, you can use the following commands :

```
[ $(du -s "$directory" | cut -f1) -gt 104857600  ] && rm -rf "$directory" || mv "$directory" /tmp/
```

To do one or the other depending on whether the input parameter points to a file or a directory, you can use `if [ -d "$path" ]; then <directory pipeline>; else <file pipeline>; fi`.

To recursively move or delete all the files of a directory depending on their size you can use the following :

```
find . -type f -a \( -size +100M -exec rm {} + -o -exec mv -t /tmp/ {} + \)
```

It first selects files in the current directory, then execute `rm ...` with the list of those files whose size is greater than 100M and `mv ... /tmp` with the rest of the files.

Comment: This can become inefficient if we talk about many files, as it creates a fork for the mv command for each file that has been found. find -exex combinations exists in the Unix world, but the "better admins" try to avoid this on commandline and in scripting.

Comment: @ennox "it creates a fork for the mv command for each file that has been found" no it doesn't, I'm using `-exec ... +` instead of `-exec ... \;` which leads to calling the command with as much files matched as possible (limited by max argument list size)

Comment: I also meant for each "matched file". What if 10.000 or more files match ? Then "find -exec" creates too much overhead by having to fork "mv" 10.000 times. I think it's recommended to think about it and to choose the better solution which can scale well even in bigger scenarios.

Comment: @ennox I must have phrased it wrong. From `man find` on `-exec command {} +` : "This  variant  of the -exec action runs the specified command on
              the selected files, but the command line is built  by  appending
              each  selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will  be  much  less  than  the  number  of
              matched  files"

Comment: So for your 10k files on a modern system that'd be a single `rm` call and `mv` call (and if you were limited by the argument list size you'd run into the problem whatever the solution you chose to use)

Comment: Ah now I understand. Sorry, big excuse. I seem to be stuck with the old syntax and GNU brought additions over the years.

Comment: @ennox NP, always a pleasure to teach someone something new, and I also discovered a problem with my command while trying to put up a demo : it seems that unlike the `-exec command \;` with `+` you need the `{}` to be the last param before the +, so the `mv` command needs to be changed into `mv -t /tmp/ {}`

Comment: thanks for your kindness and understanding, a pleasure to work with you and to learn new tricks.

Comment: How can I make this into an alias that can be run on ONE directory or ONE file? If I replace `find .` with `find abc`, it works for a file but it doesn't remove a directory.

Comment: The `find` command I provided specifically targets files, because the filesize predicate doesn't make sense for directories. You can still add another `-o` at the end that would handle directories however you see fit. About the alias, if you want the command to handle a single file/directory don't use `find` (whose job is to recurse over a directory's content) but simply test/`[`, using `stat` to retrieve the file size or `du` to retrieve the combined size of a directory's content

Comment: Do you have a code example? That is what my original question was intended to be about.

Comment: @Limero sure, I've added code for single-item processing.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible by a combination of find command and xargs / rm statement and rsync and the order in which you perform this in the script.

Like i.e.:

```
find /foo/bar -type f -size +100M -print | xargs rm
```

Where the pipeline through xargs is for efficiency, so that the rm command is not being executed for each file which has been found by find.

And next  an rsync statement to mirror a hierarchie of remaining files (from your question its not 100% clear to me whether there are subdirectories of other files or not, therefore I propose rsync which also would cover a subdir hirarchie) to a different path and using the rsync command line option

- --remove-source-files

```
rsync -av --remove source files /foo/bar /tmp
```

Conclusion: this combination of find / rsync in the proper order works much more efficient compared to other proposed solutions with "find .. -exec" where the executed program would be forked as often as a file has been found. The more advanced Unix Admins avoid "find ... -exec" not to waste valuable system resources and because it scales much better when having a lot of files.

Comment: See find manpage, then use +100M as unit.

Comment: `xargs` is not a good idea: your command will break if the filename contains spaces or quotes. `find /foo/bar -type f -size +100M -exec rm {} +` is the proper way to use `find`.

Comment: _The more advanced Unix Admins avoid "find ... -exec"_: this is just nonsense. Where did you see that? Rather, the more advanced Unix Admins _use `find` properly and avoid `xargs` like the plague!_

Comment: It was this way in the old times when it was not all about GNU commands.